# Capturing Write Routines in Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I (attempt!) to maintain a very old very large set of FORTRAN code. This code contains WRITE statements scattered throughout:

```
      WRITE(NOUT,2050)DAMPING 
2050  FORMAT(3X,'DAMPING =',F6.2,'%')
```

What I'd like to be able to do is take control of these WRITE statements. The reason for this is we need to create an additional output file (with some modifications) and it would be too much work to duplicate the statements. Instead I was hoping to modify them... One way might be to have my own write routine:

```
      WRITEF(NOUT,2050)DAMPING 
2050  FORMAT(3X,'DAMPING =',F6.2,'%')

      --------------------------------

      SUBROUTINE WRITEF(objectToWrite)
      ...
      Code to write out object
      ...
      END
```

Another might be to take the write statement as a parameter:

```
      WRITEF(WRITE(NOUT,2050)DAMPING) 
2050  FORMAT(3X,'DAMPING =',F6.2,'%')

      --------------------------------

      SUBROUTINE WRITEF(characterToWrite)
      ...
      Code to write out character
      ...
      END
```

But unfortunately I lack the FORTRAN knowledge to know if this is possible and if so how to implement it!

Comment: The second one is definitely not possible because write is not a function to return a value. It seems you only option is to refactor the code in order to gather up the write statements into a few subroutines _after_ the calculations are finished.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but unfortunately the way the code is written this wouldn't be possible - values are written out to file and then forgotten/overwritten as the calculations are running...

Comment: note that the format is only part of the problem. `write` statements generally come with arbitrary length lists of arbitrary type variables. There is no clean way to make your own function that takes such an argument list.   What you want to do *might* be a job for a preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

If you exchange the `FORMAT` statements for a format character string, you could do something like

```
  SUBROUTINE WRITE_REAL(unit,fmt, x)
    INTEGER unit
    CHARACTER(*) fmt
    REAL x
    write(unit,fmt) x
  END


  WRITEF(NOUT, "(3X,'DAMPING =',F6.2,'%')", DAMPING)
```

but I leave on you whether it is useful. I am somewhat skeptical.

Comment: There could be some use to this approach if I could grab the format statement somehow rather than writing it out... `WRITEF(NOUT, <Get Format Statement 2050>, DAMPING)`

Comment: @qu1ckdry No, if you want to do any subroutines to restructure your outputs, and you want to pass the format, you MUST drop the `FORMAT` statement and use the format string. There is no way passing the label (IIRC `ASSIGN` won't help). `FORMAT` is obsolete anyway (maybe not officially).